# Facebook new Page Plugin custom styles

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

Has anyone tried changing the CSS in the new Facebook Page plugin? Old plugin used to provide some options such as being able to select a color scheme. However, the new plugin it's white all around and it does not seem to accept my custom CSS. Example:

```
    ._h7l {

      background: transparent !important;
      border: none !important;

    }
```

Any ideas how we can get some custom CSS to work?

Comment: The content is rendered inside an iframe, and therefor you can _not_ format it using your own CSS. You’ll have to make do with the official configuration options the plugin offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the CSS. The content of the plugin is displayed inside an iframe so there is no way you can change CSS or override any javascript method.

There are different options provided by this plugin you can customize. Please take a look into the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can, but not without using a little bit of jQuery and you site must use an https protocol (https). Both protocol must match...

Start by adding this awesome plugin: [jquery.waituntilexists.js](https://gist.github.com/buu700/4200601)

And then play with your Facebook iframe by adding your css in it:

```
$(".fb-page iframe").waitUntilExists(function(){
    $(".fb-page iframe").contents().find('head').append('
       <style>._h7l {
           background: transparent !important;
           border: none !important;}
       </style>
    ');
});
```

Comment: This won't work as the domains must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

Error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://yourdomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin... from accessing a cross-origin frame